# Media Query Questions - scale down for iPhone/ mobile phones?

Tags: html, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a responsive site, which looks great on the web and on the iPad at 768px. Thing is, the application wasn't really built for the iPhone 320px wide. I really don't want to do another version - in fact it's not really an option.

My questions is this, how can I scale the entire app to fit the iphone, without affecting my media queries for the 768px responsive design (i.e. `@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 768px)`).

My current meta tag info is this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Would it make sense to use to css scale/zoom like this - targeted just for iPhone/mobile cells?

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 568px) {
    html {
        zoom: 50%;
    }
}
```

What's the best practice to scale my 768px responsive design to fit 320px-568px mobile devices? There must eb an easier way.

I don't feel comfortable with the hack above. Seems shady.

Comment: Can we see your current design? IMO Zooming the site would be a poor decision and you should really look to building an entirely collapsible site down to 320px

Comment: No can do on the showing the site. It's localhost right now. Yeah, building a responsive site for 320px won't work for our application for many reasons. We have a campaign builder that can't be built down to 320px;

Comment: I don't need the mobile version to be scaled or responsive. My normal design (viewed on web browser) is a responsive 980px design. I would be happy if this would fill the viewport on an iphone. Can't get that to work though

Comment: what does it look like if you completely remove the `meta` tags? I'd expect that on iPhone and Android that should initially make the full width viewable - but it would look poor.

Comment: If I remove `minimum-scale=1.0,` from the meta tag, on iphone it looks like any other site that wasn't media queried. Which works.

Comment: OK cool, are you happy with that solution then?

Comment: I guess...have no choice. Unless I wanted to code a 320px responsive site. Which I don't.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It sparked a resolution to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution. I removed the @Media Query zoom and also removed `minimum-scale=1.0` from the meta tag. This still allows my app's media queries for 768px to kick-in. Yet on mobile devices 320px-568px, the website will just be scaled down to fit the iphone screen. Works. Not a mobile-friendly solution, but will do. Our web-app is not meant for mobile-users (cellphones).

Comment: Sorry that I can't offer you with a better solution unless you're open to redesigning!